# cannot find symbol: method setBufferFetchSizeHint(java.lang.Integer) , & method :setDistinct(boolean)

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ebean

I use play framework 2.5 
and Ebean ORM

My code;

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
public static final Model.Finder<Long, ComEntity> select = new Finder<>(ComEntity.class);

public static List<ComEntity> getByFunction(String functionName){
    return select.setDistinct(true).where().eq("intervenant.IntFnId.FunctionName", functionName).findList();
}



    return select.setBufferFetchSizeHint(IntegerCte.DATA_SIZE_BUFFER).setMaxRows(IntegerCte.DATA_MAX_FETCHED_ROW)
            .where()
            .findList();
```

---

My Finder "select" cannot resolve the method "setDistinct(boolean)" and setBufferFetchSizeHint(int) ...
Any one can define the origin of my problem because this two methods aren't deprecated in play 2.5 and I cannot find any solution..
Please help me..

Comment: Please fix your question so that the question text and title are about the same thing.

Comment: Now show us the code that uses `setBufferFetchSizeHint`

Comment: I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select.setBufferFetchSizeHint(IntegerCte.DATA_SIZE_BUFFER)
            .where()
            .findPagedList(ZeroBasedIndex, pageSize);
```